# How to use a variable for toggling multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have a code which takes a data-text attribute from an image or a div and displays it as a description in a different div. I am using a variable to determine whether the text is showing or not. This is a problem when having more elements as the variable is shared by all the togglable elements. I want the code to work with all the divs/images that have the classes assigned but I don't know how to fix the problem with a variable. Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ws3FQ/1/) for better understanding of what I'm on about.

```
var toggled = 0;

$("#main > .item").click(
  function () {
    if(toggled == 0){
      var currentext = $(this).data("text");
      $(this).parent("div").children("div.text").text(currentext);
      toggled ++;
    }
    else{
      $(this).parent("div").children("div.text").empty();
      toggled --;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `data` function to attach the number to the element :

```
$("#main > .item").click(
  function () {
    var toggled = $(this).data('toggled')||0;
    if(toggled == 0){
      var currentext = $(this).data("text");
      $(this).parent("div").children("div.text").text(currentext);
      toggled ++;
    }
    else{
      $(this).parent("div").children("div.text").empty();
      toggled --;
    }
    $(this).data('toggled', toggled);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DP3EV/)

Comment: cleanest solution although i would just prefer `if($(this).data('toggled'))` or `if(toggled)` as you will.

Comment: @Christoph Right. I tried to just fix OP's problem, which seemed to be the attachment of the toggled variable to the element.

Comment: Doing it like this I'd make it more intuitive and rename the variable, and make it a boolean: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mGjyx/1). But yes, a nice solution.

Comment: @zsawyer could as well write `$(this).data('showing', !showing);`

Comment: @Christoph [that](http://jsfiddle.net/mGjyx/2/) is a very neat suggestion! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$("#main > .item").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('toggled')){
        $this.parent("div").children("div.text").empty();
        $this.data('toggled', false);
    }
    else{
        var currentext = $this.data("text");
        $this.parent("div").children("div.text").text(currentext);
        $this.data('toggled', true);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zG2tj/)

Comment: No explanation, and why obfuscate the code with `var $this = $(this);`? When you still use `$(this)` anyways?

Comment: @zsawyer it is always not possible to explain everything, as a user it is the OP's responsibility to try to understand the solution and if has any doubts he/she can ask them in the comments. The solution here is almost self explanatory

Comment: @zsawyer the new code which I wrote reused `$this` but missed to update the existing code base

Comment: @zsawyer I agree with Arun that explaining $this might seem unnecessary (even if it can be done on request). The -1 here seems harsh.

Comment: @dystroy you have just proved my point. I was not asking for a clarification on `$this`, as it is totally unconnected to the solution. The solution is similar to yours. Except that you have pointed out what you did, in a concise and precise single sentence, and only changed the ops code where it was vital/needed. The -1 was because of the combination of obfuscation and lack of explanation/hinting at the vital change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("#main > .item").click( function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).next('.text').text()) == "") {
        var currentext = $(this).data("text");
        $(this).next('.text').text(currentext);
    } else {
        $(this).next('.text').text("");
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ws3FQ/5/